# On Rieman integral

Tags: integration

Suppose $0\leq f$ on $[a,b]$. Could we deduce from $f^2(x)\in R[a,b]$ that $f(x)\in R[a,b]$, where $R[a,b]$ is the set of all functions that are Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Taking square roots is a well-defined continuous (hence integrable) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. If $f \geq 0$ then $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $f^2$ is also continuous at $x$, because $f(x) = \sqrt{f^2(x)}$ and the composition is continuous. The same is true if $f \leq 0$ by considering $-\sqrt{f^2(x)}$. Now use Lebesgue's criterion (a function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if and only if its set of discontinuities has measure zero).